# React Router Error: Not able to load different urls separately other than home page by build on Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, netlify

I'm a little new to react, so I have come across a problem which is on my personal portfolio website and i don't know how to solve it

the problem is when i open my website it take me to my home page which is fine, and when i go to other pages from my home page it works fine but when i want to go to about page directly than i'm unable to access it.

for example

`https://sparsh-saxena.netlify.app/`
this is my home page, if I type this as url it works fine

but If I want to open my about page or any other page on my portfolio than It doesn't work
like: `https://sparsh-saxena.netlify.app/about`

It shows-> `Page Not Found Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to support client-side routing with Netlify (which is you actual objective here). You need to support `pushState`.

To do this you need to create a `public/_redirects` file with the following rewrite rules:

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Now when you build your project for deployment it should work correctly!

TL;DR:

- create a `_redirects` file in your `public` folder of your React Project
- give it the following content: `/* /index.html 200`
- build your project
- deploy it to Netlify